# Power BI Service not allowing Parameters to be edited. Gateway connection and Scheduled Refresh also grayed out

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server

New to PowerBI.  I am publishing my reports to a folder the client created.  When they go in as shown in the screenshot they are seeing these 3 options grayed out.  How do I fix this?  I tried changing the Parameter Types to TEXT from DATE so I don't think that is the issue.  Are there some settings that need changed on the Service Side or other where I can enable these options for them?  I should mention that they are not grayed out in the folder that I made them for me, just for other users trying to access this report.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

They just need to "take over" the dataset to change those settings, just like the page says:

[image]

Comment: Ok thanks.  Does that mean any parameters used in the dataset will be editable after this change?  Basically I am asking if several people needed to access this report/dataset will they each be able to see different timeframes (like one person is looking at July while another is looking at March)?

Comment: That’s not how parameters work in Power Query.  Everyone sees the same parameter values.  Each person can use different filters or slicers.

Comment: So they could use parameters but not at the same time?  Will each person have to just click Take Over each time they need to set the date range parameters?

Comment: That's not what parameters are for.  The Dataset should include all the dates, and then users can filter in reports.

Comment: Is there a way to get a date parameter on the page like in a textbox that the user could enter start and end dates?  I have a number of queries that are summary level and don't have the dates in the dataset.

Comment: Of course;  use a slicer.  You can also use dynamic M query parameters in DirectQuery Datasets. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-dynamic-m-query-parameters